# Using scala list in java

Tags: java, scala

In scala, I can add to the end of list by,

```
val list = List[Integer](1,2,3,4)
val addEndList  = list:::List[Integer](101) //now this list has 1,2,3,4,101
```

I am trying to do it from java now,

```
scala.collection.immutable.List<Integer> list =  perform.getScalaListofSize(4); //1,2,3,4
scala.collection.immutable.List<Integer> list2 =  perform.getScalaListofSize(1); //1
scala.collection.immutable.List<Integer> list1 = list2.$colon$colon$colon(list);//1,2,3,4,1
```

Shouldn't the last line in java be:

```
list.$colon$colon$colon(list2)
```

its giving me output as

```
//1,1,2,3,4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scala methods that end with `:` are right-associative when used with infix notation:  If you do `a ::: b` in Scala it invokes `b.:::(a)`.  In your manual Java invocation you have to transpose the arguments yourself, as you discovered.

Comment: Actually, he means *methods*. It's not a function, and Scala doesn't really have operators.

Comment: You might say "right-associative _when used in infix notation_".